# /etc/profile is a directory

Tags: linux, bash, redhat

On my RHEL8, the /etc/profile is a directory rather than a file therefore when starting a ssh connection with the computer, I get `bash: /etc/profile: is a directory`. I can see the directory there as I can `cd` into it and it contains multiple .sh or .csh files. I can also locate the profile file inside it indicating the executing path should be `/etc/profile/profile` rather than `/etc/profile`.

The reason that I need to fix this issue is because I want to put customised shell files in the /etc/profile.d directory but it is only called when /etc/profile is actually called. In this case, it isn't called because of the /etc/profile is directory error.

I have tried to do `sudo cp /etc/profile/profile /etc/profile` to see if I copy the file path to /etc directory will work; however, I get `cp: '/etc/profile/profile' and '/etc/profile/profile' are the same file`.

Helps will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Rename or move the /etc/profile directory somewhere out of the way, *then* move the files into their correct locations.

Comment: Yes, that works now thank you!

Comment: I would be more worried about, why this directory came into existence. Modifications in `/etc` require root rights, and since there are files in this directory, what purpose do they have? Who put them there?

Comment: ... and what else is wrong now and could become wrong in future given someone/something with root privileges created that directory and so could have done just about anything else? You should really figure out exactly how that happened before doing anything else.

Comment: In the limit, the easiest way to get back to sanity may be to (save your local files if you didn't already), reinstall the system, and restore your files from backups.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> On my RHEL8, the /etc/profile is a directory rather than a file

I don't know how that situation arose, but it is not normal of RHEL8 and not correct with respect to RHEL's default shell, Bash.

> I can see the directory there as I can cd into it and it contains multiple .sh or .csh files.

Are you sure you're not looking at `/etc/profile.d`?  On RHEL, Ubuntu, and some other distributions, that is indeed a directory such as you describe.

> I can also locate the profile file inside it indicating the executing path should be `/etc/profile/profile` rather than `/etc/profile`.

I take that instead as an indication that your system configuration has been mangled.  It's impossible for me to say whether that was intentional or accidental, and if intentional, whether it was meant to be beneficial or malicious.  In any case, it has evidently had some unwanted effects.

> I have tried to do `sudo cp /etc/profile/profile /etc/profile` to see if I copy the file path to /etc directory will work; however, I get `cp: '/etc/profile/profile' and '/etc/profile/profile' are the same file`.

To get back to a standard configuration, rename directory `/etc/profile` to something else, say `/etc/profile.oops`.  Then move the `profile` script out of it to its normal position: `sudo mv /etc/profile.oops/profile /etc/profile`.

But be well aware that depending on how this issue arose, there may be other issues that need to be resolved.  For example, it might be that some of the scripts presently in your `/etc/profile` directory ought to be in `/etc/profile.d` instead.  Might.  Or if the change was associated with the machine having been compromised by a malicious adversary then your best bet would probably be to perform a complete wipe and reinstallation.

Comment: I am not sure if this might be the reason but I accidentally deleted the /etc/profile which might prompt the OS to convert /etc/profile.d to /etc/profile? On top of that, in the /etc/profile directory, it also contains other .sh files such as which2, vim, less, lang..., I am not sure if they belong to /etc or /etc/profile.d directory. I am hoping to not reinstall the OS if possible.

Comment: @cloudchang, reinstalling the OS is probably a good choice if that's not too disruptive.  I speculate that among the things that happened to you is that your original `/etc/profile.d` was renamed to `/etc/profile`.  That might, in fact, be *how* your original `/etc/profile` was destroyed, and how you got the scripts you see in directory `/etc/profile` subsequent system updates could well have created a new `/etc/profile.d` with the contents you now see -- including, possibly, `/etc/profile/profile`.